# How can i fetch elements from an ndarray per row?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to fetch each row in an numpy.ndarray and transform it. for instance:

```
for each row i in array a
    r=random number
    for each element j in row i:
        a[i][j]=a[i][j]*r
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to create first the matrix `r` where it holds the corresponding weights per cell of `a`. Then, do the multiplication. So, you can take the benefits of vectorization.

Example:

```
r = np.zeros(a.shape)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        # compute r[i, j]

a = a * r
```

If your random numbers do not depend on the cells of `a`, just run:

```
a = a * numpy.random.rand(a.shape[0], a.shape[1])
```

And if you want your random numbers not to change for columns, then you can take the benefit of [broadcasting](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2000/09/27/numerically.html?page=2):

```
a = a * numpy.random.rand(a.shape[0], 1)
```

For iterating over arrays, you can check [this documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html).

Answer (score 0):

The way to access a `numpy.ndarray` element is:

```
a[i,j]=a[i,j]*r
```